# Puzzled by an undefined service class member variable that was actually previously defined

Tags: angular

I have a service with a member variable that is set by a method, and then referenced by another method in the same service.

I was wondering if I had multiple instances of the service, so the constructor ensures the service is not instantiated twice, and since no such error is thrown I understand the service is instantiated only once.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PwaService implements OnDestroy {

  private installPromptEvent?: Event;

  constructor(
    // Ensure the service is injected only once
    @Optional() @SkipSelf() pwaService: PwaService,
  ) {
    if (pwaService) {
      throw new Error('The PWA service has ALREADY been injected.');
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', this.handleBbeforeInstallAndroid);
  }

  private handleBbeforeInstallAndroid(event: Event): void {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.installPromptEvent = event;
    console.log(this.installPromptEvent);
  }

  private receivedInstallPromptEventAndroid(): boolean {
    console.log(this.installPromptEvent);
    console.log(this.installPromptEvent != null);
    return this.installPromptEvent != null;
  }

  private isInstallable(): boolean {
    if (this.platform.ANDROID) {
      return this.receivedInstallPromptEventAndroid() && !this.isInStandaloneModeAndroid();
    } else if (this.platform.IOS) {
      return this.isInStandaloneModeIOS();
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  public checkForBeforeInstallEvents(): void {
    if (this.platform.ANDROID) {
      if (!this.isInStandaloneModeAndroid()) {
        window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', this.handleBbeforeInstallAndroid);
      }
    }
  }
```

The logger in the `handleBbeforeInstallAndroid` method does display the received event fine.

But the logger in the `receivedInstallPromptEventAndroid` method shows an undefined `installPromptEvent` member variable.

The event listener is registered in the module:

```
const checkForBeforeInstallEvents: Function = (pwaService: PwaService) => () => pwaService.checkForBeforeInstallEvents();

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: checkForBeforeInstallEvents,
      deps: [PwaService],
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class LibPwaModule { }
```

UPDATE: Folowing ConnorsFan's advice (I liked him a lot too at Flushing Meadows :-) I tried the following:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', () => { this.handleBbeforeInstallAndroid });
```

but the method would simply not be called at all.

Then I tried an explicit bind statement as in:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', this.handleBbeforeInstallAndroid.bind(this));
```

And this time, it worked fine and the `this.installPromptEvent` member variable was correctly retrieved.

As I got this from ConnorsFan's commment, I'd be happy to accept his solution.

Comment: Can we see the `addEventListener` part? I am 90% sure that this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

Comment: Try `window.addEventListener('beforeinstallprompt', () => { this.handleBbeforeInstallAndroid(); });`. Or define the handler as an arrow function: `private handleBbeforeInstallAndroid = (event: Event): void => { ... }`.

Comment: Glad to know that (1) the suggestion worked and (2) you also like Jimmy Connors. :-) I will not post an answer since this is a duplicate of a frequently asked question.

Comment: In my original comment, I forgot the parentheses in the arrow function. That is why the function was not called. The modified comment should work.